# Converting an optimized for addition loop into inline assembly (0.8.20)

Tags: solidity, gas, assembly, optimization

I have to loop through an array that will contain <10 addresses. I've already optimized for gas costs as much as possible using native Solidity. But I realized this loop can be improved further with inline assembly. As I am completely new to assembly I'm interested to see what this code would look like.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

contract Optimized {

    address[] private specialaccounts;

    struct Amounts {
        uint amount;
    }
    
    mapping (address => Amounts) accounts;

    function optimizedAddLoopNativeSolidity() public view returns (uint result) {
      unchecked {
        uint i; uint len = specialaccounts.length;
        for (; i<len;) {
            if (specialaccounts[i] != address(0)) {
                result += accounts[specialaccounts[i]].amount;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return result;
      }
    }

    function sameAddLoopButAssembly() public view returns (uint result) {
        assembly ("memory-safe") {
            // code here
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've augmented your example to make the connections between the slots clearer

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract Optimized {

    address[10] public  specialaccounts; //slot 0 - 9

    struct Amounts {
        uint amount;
    }
    mapping (address => Amounts) accounts;  //slot 10

    constructor() {
        for (uint i; i<10;) {
            specialaccounts[i] = address(uint160(i + (1<<100)));
            Amounts memory a = Amounts(10 + i);
            accounts[specialaccounts[i]] = a;
            ++i;
        }        
    }

    function optimizedAddLoopNativeSolidity() public view returns (uint result) {
        uint i; 
        uint len = specialaccounts.length;
        unchecked {
            for (; i<len;) {
                if (specialaccounts[i] != address(0)) {
                    result += accounts[specialaccounts[i]].amount;
                }
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }

    function sameAddLoopButAssembly() public view returns (uint result) {
        assembly ("memory-safe") {
            for { let n := 0 } lt(n, 10) { n := add(n, 1) } { 
                let addr := sload(n)
                if gt(addr, 0) {
                    //get specialaccounts[n] 
                    mstore(0, addr)
                    //link to slot 10
                    mstore(32, 10) 
                    //get link from mapping
                    let hash := keccak256(0, 64)
                    // add result and value from accounts
                    result := add(result, sload(hash))
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```